# how to check that the email id exist in domain without sending any mails using java

Tags: java, dns, email-validation

Is there any way to verify where the email id exist in domain or not?

I am having the following function: it checks only for valid domain, but i need to check for valid email address in domain without sending any mails.

```
 public boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
   boolean result = true;

   try {
      InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
      emailAddr.validate();

   } catch (AddressException ex) {
      result = false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean emails from your internal organization? If so, knowing the mail server used would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a source code that could do many type of verification, I've been using it for years :

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html

Note : see the function isAddressValid() in the page for full validation.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre Lavoie for your response.I referred your that link it checks only for valid domain but not checks for valid email address .

Comment: The function isAddressValid() do all the test, also try to connect to the SMTP server as @Brian Agnew told. But use with caution, it not always work! Generally I only validate email syntax, domain existance and MX existance in that domain.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [SMTP VRFY command](http://the-welters.com/professional/smtp.html):

> This command will request that the receiving SMTP server verify that a
>   given email username is valid. The SMTP server will reply with the
>   login name of the user. This feature can be turned off in sendmail
>   because allowing it can be a security hole. VRFY commands can be used
>   to probe for login names on a system. See the security section below
>   for information about turning off this feature.

Note the security issues above though.

Comment: Thank you Brian Agnew for your response.But how to use this command in java function.

Comment: You can create a connection to port 25 on your SMTP server (try with telnet) and just do 'VRFY address'