# java email validation commons-validator EmailValidation

Tags: java, validation, email

I use to use emailvalidator from apache common-validator, but it is not developing anymore and does not support new domain names, like acamedy, radio.

Is there any replacement or I need to check email through pattern matching?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
boolean result = true;
try {
  InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
  emailAddr.validate();
} catch (AddressException ex) {
  result = false;
}
 return result;
}
```

UPDATE: 
I found a second alternative, where you can use SMTP commands to check whether there is a registered email server in the domain! Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453160/how-to-check-that-the-email-id-exist-in-domain-without-sending-any-mails-using-j) topic, where you can find [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html) code and an explanation on [SMTP VRFY commands](http://the-welters.com/professional/smtp.html)!

Comment: I can, but it will not check correctness of domain names. And I can not decline local email @name without domain ending.

Comment: It's true! It came to my mind after reading email validation, but it's not as powerful you want it to be! I don't know if there is an up-to-date alternative like the common-validator!

Comment: The only way to reliably check a domain name is by doing a DNS Query. test@hfgsdfsdfsdfs.com looks ok but doesn't exists. narwhal@domaintest.みんな might look strange but is a valid email address.

Comment: why common-validator does not develop anymore?