# How to check email address is exists or not on server side in java

Tags: java

I want to validate an email address in Java before sending an email.
That email address may exist on the server or not.

How can I  test it?
I don't have any idea.

Is there a way to check that a given email address exists on the server side?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453160/how-to-check-that-the-email-id-exist-in-domain-without-sending-any-mails-using-j

Answer (score 0):

If you are store your email addresses in database, you need to create method that fetch the email address from the database, and your method is completely depends on the technologies and DBMS that you are working on.

```
public boolean isEmailExist(String email) {

   String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?";
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
   preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
   ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);

   return rs.next();               
}
```

I hope this helpful, enjoy!

Comment: my requirement to validate the email id on mail server wheather it exist on mail server or not.                                                                                        Is there anyway to check that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

This is one example of a very general kind of problem: trying to predict the future. The most effective way to test whether *any* resource is valid and available is to *try to use it* in the normal way. Anything else is basically fortune-telling. It might be valid at the moment you test it and invalid when you try to use it, or *vice versa.*

This applies to files, email addresses, servers, ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no straight forward way to check if the email address is available on the mail server or not in Java. There is a workaround for it, see this post:

[Verify email in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153716/verify-email-in-java#answer-153751)